# AWS Apprunner Failing Health Check when pytorch is involved. But container works well on local

Tags: python, deployment, pytorch, aws-app-runner

I have been experimenting with AWS app runner. I found a basic tutorial code that uses flask. Here is the code :

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/app')
def blog():
    return "Hello, from App!"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=80)
```

and here is the docker file

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

I easily managed to deploy this setup on Apprunner. However, when I tried to deploy my app it was throwing me an error related to a health check.  But my local container worked fine without errors. So it means there compatibility issue with apprunner.

> 09-19-2023 08:10:37 PM [AppRunner] Deployment with ID : da2bb9----- failed. Failure reason : Health check failed.
> 09-19-2023 08:10:25 PM [AppRunner] Health check failed on port '80'. Check your configured port number. For more information, read the application logs.
> 09-19-2023 08:04:14 PM [AppRunner] Performing health check on port '80'.
> 09-19-2023 08:04:04 PM [AppRunner] Provisioning instances and deploying image for publicly accessible service.
> 09-19-2023 08:03:53 PM [AppRunner] Successfully copied the image from ECR.
> 09-19-2023 07:52:50 PM [AppRunner] Deployment Artifact :- Repo Type: ECR; Image URL : 218512261774.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test7; Image Tag : new
> 09-19-2023 07:52:50 PM [AppRunner] Deployment with ID : da2bb9532------- started. Triggering event: SERVICE_CREATE

I tried to pinpoint the reason and in the end, I ended up deploying 7 different images with various code configurations. In the end, I ended up creating minimal replication of the issue by adding torch=2.0.1 dependency (i was experimenting with python 3.10, but everything else was same ) to the requirements.txt file

I also tried with python3.10. passes health check without torch, fails with torch installed.  I also experimented with different ports.

My question is what might be the cause of this issue and how may I fix it.  I must say I am quite new to containers and AWS deployment. but I have done my research and couldnt find any solution

Comment: Did you check the security group of AWS Apprunner ?

Comment: i am able to deploy without any issue if there is no torch dependency. therefore it cant be about security config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works without a problem if you use cpu version of Pytorch.
Add this line to dockerfile just after the `requirements.txt`. (And if you have other dependencies which are using torch, also add them after this line so they will be installed based on this version of the torch. )

`RUN pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu`

(add all of it. https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu link included)